# SAS SQL JOIN output to a table

Tags: sql, sas

I have a question about the output table from the SAS SQL JOIN.
Here are my sample codes:

```
data payroll;
   input IdNumber $4. +3 Gender $1. +4 Jobcode $3. +9 Salary 5.
         +2 Birth date7. +2 Hired date7.;
   informat birth date7. hired date7.;
   format birth date7. hired date7.;
   datalines;
1919   M    TA2         34376  12SEP60  04JUN87
1653   F    ME2         35108  15OCT64  09AUG90
1400   M    ME1         29769  05NOV67  16OCT90
1350   F    FA3         32886  31AUG65  29JUL90
1401   M    TA3         38822  13DEC50  17NOV85
1499   M    ME3         43025  26APR54  07JUN80
1101   M    SCP         18723  06JUN62  01OCT90
1333   M    PT2         88606  30MAR61  10FEB81
1402   M    TA2         32615  17JAN63  02DEC90
1479   F    TA3         38785  22DEC68  05OCT89
1403   M    ME1         28072  28JAN69  21DEC91
1739   M    PT1         66517  25DEC64  27JAN91
1658   M    SCP         17943  08APR67  29FEB92
1428   F    PT1         68767  04APR60  16NOV91
1782   M    ME2         35345  04DEC70  22FEB92
1244   M    ME2         36925  31AUG63  17JAN88
1383   M    BCK         25823  25JAN68  20OCT92
1574   M    FA2         28572  27APR60  20DEC92
1789   M    SCP         18326  25JAN57  11APR78
1404   M    PT2         91376  24FEB53  01JAN80
1437   F    FA3         33104  20SEP60  31AUG84
1639   F    TA3         40260  26JUN57  28JAN84
1269   M    NA1         41690  03MAY72  28NOV92
1065   M    ME2         35090  26JAN44  07JAN87
1876   M    TA3         39675  20MAY58  27APR85
1037   F    TA1         28558  10APR64  13SEP92
1129   F    ME2         34929  08DEC61  17AUG91
1988   M    FA3         32217  30NOV59  18SEP84
1405   M    SCP         18056  05MAR66  26JAN92
1430   F    TA2         32925  28FEB62  27APR87
1983   F    FA3         33419  28FEB62  27APR87
1134   F    TA2         33462  05MAR69  21DEC88
1118   M    PT3        111379  16JAN44  18DEC80
1438   F    TA3         39223  15MAR65  18NOV87
1125   F    FA2         28888  08NOV68  11DEC87
1475   F    FA2         27787  15DEC61  13JUL90
1117   M    TA3         39771  05JUN63  13AUG92
1935   F    NA2         51081  28MAR54  16OCT81
1124   F    FA1         23177  10JUL58  01OCT90
1422   F    FA1         22454  04JUN64  06APR91
1616   F    TA2         34137  01MAR70  04JUN93
1406   M    ME2         35185  08MAR61  17FEB87
1120   M    ME1         28619  11SEP72  07OCT93
1094   M    FA1         22268  02APR70  17APR91
1389   M    BCK         25028  15JUL59  18AUG90
1905   M    PT1         65111  16APR72  29MAY92
1407   M    PT1         68096  23MAR69  18MAR90
1114   F    TA2         32928  18SEP69  27JUN87
1410   M    PT2         84685  03MAY67  07NOV86
1439   F    PT1         70736  06MAR64  10SEP90
1409   M    ME3         41551  19APR50  22OCT81
1408   M    TA2         34138  29MAR60  14OCT87
1121   M    ME1         29112  26SEP71  07DEC91
1991   F    TA1         27645  07MAY72  12DEC92
1102   M    TA2         34542  01OCT59  15APR91
1356   M    ME2         36869  26SEP57  22FEB83
1545   M    PT1         66130  12AUG59  29MAY90
1292   F    ME2         36691  28OCT64  02JUL89
1440   F    ME2         35757  27SEP62  09APR91
1368   M    FA2         27808  11JUN61  03NOV84
1369   M    TA2         33705  28DEC61  13MAR87
1411   M    FA2         27265  27MAY61  01DEC89
1113   F    FA1         22367  15JAN68  17OCT91
1704   M    BCK         25465  30AUG66  28JUN87
1900   M    ME2         35105  25MAY62  27OCT87
1126   F    TA3         40899  28MAY63  21NOV80
1677   M    BCK         26007  05NOV63  27MAR89
1441   F    FA2         27158  19NOV69  23MAR91
1421   M    TA2         33155  08JAN59  28FEB90
1119   M    TA1         26924  20JUN62  06SEP88
1834   M    BCK         26896  08FEB72  02JUL92
1777   M    PT3        109630  23SEP51  21JUN81
1663   M    BCK         26452  11JAN67  11AUG91
1106   M    PT2         89632  06NOV57  16AUG84
1103   F    FA1         23738  16FEB68  23JUL92
1477   M    FA2         28566  21MAR64  07MAR88
1476   F    TA2         34803  30MAY66  17MAR87
1379   M    ME3         42264  08AUG61  10JUN84
1104   M    SCP         17946  25APR63  10JUN91
1009   M    TA1         28880  02MAR59  26MAR92
1412   M    ME1         27799  18JUN56  05DEC91
1115   F    FA3         32699  22AUG60  29FEB80
1128   F    TA2         32777  23MAY65  20OCT90
1442   F    PT2         84536  05SEP66  12APR88
1417   M    NA2         52270  27JUN64  07MAR89
1478   M    PT2         84203  09AUG59  24OCT90
1673   M    BCK         25477  27FEB70  15JUL91
1839   F    NA1         43433  29NOV70  03JUL93
1347   M    TA3         40079  21SEP67  06SEP84
1423   F    ME2         35773  14MAY68  19AUG90
1200   F    ME1         27816  10JAN71  14AUG92
1970   F    FA1         22615  25SEP64  12MAR91
1521   M    ME3         41526  12APR63  13JUL88
1354   F    SCP         18335  29MAY71  16JUN92
1424   F    FA2         28978  04AUG69  11DEC89
1132   F    FA1         22413  30MAY72  22OCT93
1845   M    BCK         25996  20NOV59  22MAR80
1556   M    PT1         71349  22JUN64  11DEC91
1413   M    FA2         27435  16SEP65  02JAN90
1123   F    TA1         28407  31OCT72  05DEC92
1907   M    TA2         33329  15NOV60  06JUL87
1436   F    TA2         34475  11JUN64  12MAR87
1385   M    ME3         43900  16JAN62  01APR86
1432   F    ME2         35327  03NOV61  10FEB85
1111   M    NA1         40586  14JUL73  31OCT92
1116   F    FA1         22862  28SEP69  21MAR91
1352   M    NA2         53798  02DEC60  16OCT86
1555   F    FA2         27499  16MAR68  04JUL92
1038   F    TA1         26533  09NOV69  23NOV91
1420   M    ME3         43071  19FEB65  22JUL87
1561   M    TA2         34514  30NOV63  07OCT87
1434   F    FA2         28622  11JUL62  28OCT90
1414   M    FA1         23644  24MAR72  12APR92
1112   M    TA1         26905  29NOV64  07DEC92
1390   M    FA2         27761  19FEB65  23JUN91
1332   M    NA1         42178  17SEP70  04JUN91
1890   M    PT2         91908  20JUL51  25NOV79
1429   F    TA1         27939  28FEB60  07AUG92
1107   M    PT2         89977  09JUN54  10FEB79
1908   F    TA2         32995  10DEC69  23APR90
1830   F    PT2         84471  27MAY57  29JAN83
1882   M    ME3         41538  10JUL57  21NOV78
1050   M    ME2         35167  14JUL63  24AUG86
1425   F    FA1         23979  28DEC71  28FEB93
1928   M    PT2         89858  16SEP54  13JUL90
1480   F    TA3         39583  03SEP57  25MAR81
1100   M    BCK         25004  01DEC60  07MAY88
1995   F    ME1         28810  24AUG73  19SEP93
1135   F    FA2         27321  20SEP60  31MAR90
1415   M    FA2         28278  09MAR58  12FEB88
1076   M    PT1         66558  14OCT55  03OCT91
1426   F    TA2         32991  05DEC66  25JUN90
1564   F    SCP         18833  12APR62  01JUL92
1221   F    FA2         27896  22SEP67  04OCT91
1133   M    TA1         27701  13JUL66  12FEB92
1435   F    TA3         38808  12MAY59  08FEB80
1418   M    ME1         28005  29MAR57  06JAN92
1017   M    TA3         40858  28DEC57  16OCT81
1443   F    NA1         42274  17NOV68  29AUG91
1131   F    TA2         32575  26DEC71  19APR91
1427   F    TA2         34046  31OCT70  30JAN90
1036   F    TA3         39392  19MAY65  23OCT84
1130   F    FA1         23916  16MAY71  05JUN92
1127   F    TA2         33011  09NOV64  07DEC86
1433   F    FA3         32982  08JUL66  17JAN87
1431   F    FA3         33230  09JUN64  05APR88
1122   F    FA2         27956  01MAY63  27NOV88
1105   M    ME2         34805  01MAR62  13AUG90
;
data payroll2;
   input idnum $4. +3 gender $1. +4 jobcode $3. +9 salary 5.
         +2 birth date7. +2 hired date7.;
   informat birth date7. hired date7.;
   format birth date7. hired date7.;
   datalines;
1639   F    TA3         42260  26JUN57  28JAN84
1065   M    ME3         38090  26JAN44  07JAN87
1561   M    TA3         36514  30NOV63  07OCT87
1221   F    FA3         29896  22SEP67  04OCT91
1447   F    FA1         22123  07AUG72  29OCT92
1998   M    SCP         23100  10SEP70  02NOV92
1036   F    TA3         42465  19MAY65  23OCT84
1106   M    PT3         94039  06NOV57  16AUG84
1129   F    ME3         36758  08DEC61  17AUG91
1350   F    FA3         36098  31AUG65  29JUL90
1369   M    TA3         36598  28DEC61  13MAR87
1076   M    PT1         69742  14OCT55  03OCT91
;
```

when I use:

```
proc sql outobs=10;
select p.IdNumber, p.Jobcode, p.Salary,
          p2.jobcode label='New Jobcode',
          p2.salary label='New Salary' format=dollar8.
from payroll as p left join payroll2 as p2
on p.IdNumber=p2.idnum;
```

the instant output contains 'New Jobcode' and 'New Salary'.
However, when I try to save the output as a table:

```
proc sql outobs=10;
create table test as
select p.IdNumber, p.Jobcode, p.Salary,
          p2.jobcode label='New Jobcode',
          p2.salary label='New Salary' format=dollar8.
from payroll as p left join payroll2 as p2
on p.IdNumber=p2.idnum;
proc print
    data=test;
run;
```

The output does not have the 'New Jobcode' and 'New Salary' as columns.
Does anyone know why this would happen? what's the difference between the instant output from SAS SQL and the saved table?

Comment: You never told it to change the NAME of the variable. Just the LABEL metadata attached to the variable.

Comment: @Tom I got your point, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `label`, try using `as`:

```
select p.IdNumber, p.Jobcode, p.Salary,
       p2.jobcode as new_jobcode, 
       p2.salary  as new_salary format=dollar8.
```

`as` is the SQL standard for assigning a name to a column.

Comment: It works! thank you. It's weird that the SAS official documentation uses 'label' rather than 'as' [link](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=sqlproc&docsetTarget=n0j12x4wxbarspn12fkpcrhwo9er.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en)

Comment: PROC SQL will use the LABEL associated with a variable as the column header (unless you tell it NOT to) in the print out.  So in the example they are just showing you how to change the column headers in the print out.  But when SQL creates an actual dataset each variable needs to have its own NAME.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
proc sql outobs=10;
create table test as select p.IdNumber, p.jobcode,p.salary,
          p2.jobcode as New_Jobcode,
          p2.salary as New_Salary format=dollar8.
from payroll as p left join payroll2 as p2
on p.IdNumber=p2.idnum;
quit;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).